# Error:Cannot call methods on nvarchar(max) ,replace xml attribute with new value

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

```
UPDATE tblCropMaster 
SET VersionXml.modify('replace value of (/root/State/stateid[@ID=("S003")]/stateid/text())[1] with ("0")')
WHERE CropId = 'Co_1'
```

Comment: You need to provide error details and ask a specific question.

Comment: What is the **datatype** of your `VersionXml` column? It **must be** `XML` for this to work! Also: what **RDBMS** is this for?? SQL is just the **query language**, used by many RDBMS - that doesn't help us - we need to know whether you're using `mysql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2` or whatever else you might be using

Comment: Added `sql-server` tag based on `nvarchar(max)`